# gmaps4rails: multiple objects (json)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

In the controller I would like to try something like this:

```
@json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails
@json << Admin.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

But thats not gonna work. Is there a standard implementation how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
json_hash  = JSON.parse(User.all.to_gmaps4rails)
json_hash2 = JSON.parse(Admin.all.to_gmaps4rails)
@json      = (json_hash + json_hash2).to_json
```

Not terrific, maybe I should patch the gem.

Comment: json_hash and json_hash2 are arrays after parsing them, so the following code works fine for me:

json_hash  = JSON.parse(User.all.to_gmaps4rails)
json_hash2 = JSON.parse(Admin.all.to_gmaps4rails)
@json      = (json_hash | (json_hash2)).to_json

But thank you very much for your fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
(JSON.parse( User.all.to_gmaps4rails) + JSON.parse( Admin.all.to_gmaps4rails)).to_json
```